# using npm to install a development version

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, alasql

There is a minor issue with [alasql](https://github.com/agershun/alasql), and the developer has kindly suggested using `v0.3.6-develop-1476` instead of just `v0.3.6` for now, and the issue will be corrected very soon.

I know very little about **npm** except how to install, remove, and list.  and using '--only=dev' didnt seem to work, even after removing and installing:

```
npm   remove  alasql;
npm  i   --only=dev   alasql;   // this did not install develop-1476
```

My question:  how do i install developer version #1476?   Here is the [0.3.6-develop-1476](https://cdn.rawgit.com/agershun/alasql/f19e17eeb908638ef320539e5b80357bfcc0709d/dist/alasql.js) github information.

Is there some way to use `git clone` instead of npm?  Or perhaps combine the two?

Thank you very much, and I apologize for asking such a basic question.

Comment: installing the normal alasql will get you v0.3.6-dev.
Check out the version at the top of the file.
https://github.com/agershun/alasql/blob/develop/dist/alasql.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [commit history](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/commit/f19e17eeb908638ef320539e5b80357bfcc0709d), we now know that the commit-SHA of the commit which bumped the version to `0.3.6-develop-1476` is `f19e17eeb908638ef320539e5b80357bfcc0709d` . So, all you need to do is:

```
npm install 'https://github.com/agershun/alasql#f19e17eeb908638ef320539e5b80357bfcc0709d' --verbose
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Going into the jsfiddle and manually grabbing the alasql.js URL, and wget/cp the file works (sort of), but your solution is FAR cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

From `npm` you can only point to a version, single git commit or tag name.

> ### Synopsis (from [`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) documentation)
>
> ```
> npm install (with no args, in package dir)
> npm install [<@scope>/]<name>
> npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<tag>
> npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version>
> npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version range>
> npm install <tarball file>
> npm install <tarball url>
> npm install <folder>
> ```

In your case:

```
# to install "develop" branch name
npm install agershun/alasql#develop 

# to install specific commit version
npm install agershun/alasql#f19e17eeb908638ef320539e5b80357bfcc0709d
```

Remember to use `--save` if your want make it persistent.